# Azure Media Services <Quality> in thumbnails

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am using azure media services for video content management. For this I am also generating thumbnails using xml preset file as provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-generate-thumbnail-with-mes).
But I am not able to understand the significance of **Quality** here. I am not able to find much documentation for this. I understand the common definition of the word. But will it impact the time taken for encoding, any cost difference etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

It only impacts the JPEG compression.  0-100%, similar to 1-10 in Photoshop when compressing a JPEG. It's going to just crunch your JPEG down with more compression and artifacts.  A typical setting of 70-80% is usually a good enough quality for a JPEG.  If you are using PNG, you don't need to set it.

It does not affect the performance, cost, etc. of the Thumbnail job.